# change widget to display excerpt instead of content

Tags: widgets

For the life of me I can not figure out how to get this widget (built into the theme) to show the excerpt instead of the post content. Can you guys take a look at it for me please. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// =============================== Latest news posts Widget (particular category) ======================================

class latest_post1 extends WP_Widget {
    function latest_post1() {
    //Constructor
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'widget Latest News', 'description' => 'List of latest posts in particular category' );
        $this->WP_Widget('latest_post1', 'PT &rarr; Latest News', $widget_ops);
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
    // prints the widget

        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
        echo $before_widget;
        $title = empty($instance['title']) ? '' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
        $category = empty($instance['category']) ? '&nbsp;' : apply_filters('widget_category', $instance['category']);
        $post_number = empty($instance['post_number']) ? '&nbsp;' : apply_filters('widget_post_number', $instance['post_number']);
        $post_link = empty($instance['post_link']) ? '&nbsp;' : apply_filters('widget_post_link', $instance['post_link']);

        // if ( !empty( $title ) ) { echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; };
        echo '';
         ?>

          <?php if($title){?> 
                <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>          
                <?php }  ?>

          <div class="latestpost">
                <?php 
                    global $post;
                    $latest_menus = get_posts('numberposts='.$post_number.'postlink='.$post_link.'&category='.$category.'');
                    foreach($latest_menus as $post) :
                    setup_postdata($post);
                ?>
                 <?php $post_images = bdw_get_images($post->ID,'large');?>




            <div class="post_list">
                <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                <cite>By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></cite>
                <div class="date"> <?php the_time('jS F')  ?></div>
            </div>            






<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php

        echo ' </div>';

        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    //save the widget
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['category'] = strip_tags($new_instance['category']);
        $instance['post_number'] = strip_tags($new_instance['post_number']);
        $instance['post_link'] = strip_tags($new_instance['post_link']);
        return $instance;

    }

    function form($instance) {
    //widgetform in backend
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '', 'category' => '', 'post_number' => '' ) );
        $title = strip_tags($instance['title']);
        $category = strip_tags($instance['category']);
        $post_number = strip_tags($instance['post_number']);
        $post_link = strip_tags($instance['post_link']);

?>
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title:
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($title); ?>" />
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>">Categories (<code>IDs</code> separated by commas):
  <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('category'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($category); ?>" />
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post_number'); ?>">Number of posts:
  <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post_number'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('post_number'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($post_number); ?>" />
  </label>
</p>
<?php
    }

}

register_widget('latest_post1');
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont see anywhere on the code that it adds either full text or excerpt. So I decided to test the widget and that's exactly what I got. There is no post content being output.

So my suggestion is to just add

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Wherever you want it to output... eg just after the thumb.

```
<?php $post_images = bdw_get_images($post->ID,'large');?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

I tested it and it worked fine.